# Unpack items and add a new one

Tags: python, list, merge

I need to create a new list merging two lists where one of them is a list of lists. Here's what I need to do:

```
a = [[2, 1, 4, 5, 0], [3, 6, 5, 4, 8], [2, 1, 4, 7, 8], [3, 4, 9, 5, 6], [7, 5, 2, 1, 1]]
b = [2, 3, 5, 0, 8]
c = []

for indx, item in enumerate(a):
    c.append([item, b[indx]])
```

This generates `c` as:

```
[[[2, 1, 4, 5, 0], 2], [[3, 6, 5, 4, 8], 3], [[2, 1, 4, 7, 8], 5], [[3, 4, 9, 5, 6], 0], [[7, 5, 2, 1, 1], 8]]
```

but I would need it to look like:

```
[[2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 2], [3, 6, 5, 4, 8, 3], [2, 1, 4, 7, 8, 5], [3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 0], [7, 5, 2, 1, 1], 8]
```

I've tried adding a `*` in front of `item` to unpack the elements but that doesn't work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just concatenate the items to create a *new* list from `item` and the element from `b`:

```
for indx, item in enumerate(a):
    c.append(item + [b[indx]])
```

You can simplify your loop using the [`zip()` function](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip):

```
for a_item, b_item in zip(a, b):
    c.append(a_item + [b_item])
```

Then move the whole definition of `c` to a list comprehension:

```
c = [a_item + [b_item] for a_item, b_item in zip(a, b)]
```

Demo:

```
>>> a = [[2, 1, 4, 5, 0], [3, 6, 5, 4, 8], [2, 1, 4, 7, 8], [3, 4, 9, 5, 6], [7, 5, 2, 1, 1]]
>>> b = [2, 3, 5, 0, 8]
>>> [a_item + [b_item] for a_item, b_item in zip(a, b)]
[[2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 2], [3, 6, 5, 4, 8, 3], [2, 1, 4, 7, 8, 5], [3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 0], [7, 5, 2, 1, 1, 8]]
```

Answer (score 2):

You can make use of [`zip()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#zip) function and *list comprehension*:

```
>>> a = [[2, 1, 4, 5, 0], [3, 6, 5, 4, 8], [2, 1, 4, 7, 8], [3, 4, 9, 5, 6], [7, 5, 2, 1, 1]]
>>> b = [2, 3, 5, 0, 8]
>>> [elem1 + [elem2] for elem1, elem2 in zip(a, b)]
[[2, 1, 4, 5, 0, 2], [3, 6, 5, 4, 8, 3], [2, 1, 4, 7, 8, 5], [3, 4, 9, 5, 6, 0], [7, 5, 2, 1, 1, 8]]
```